# rosdep update ssl cert error

Tags: rosdep, osx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm trying to install ROS Indigo for OSX (Yosemite) using the instructions on the official site, and when I get to the step where you update the ros dependencies (rosdep update), this is what it shows:

```
reading in sources list data from /etc/ros/rosdep/sources.list.d
ERROR: unable to process source [https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mikepurvis/ros-install-osx/master/rosdeps.yaml]:
    <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:590)> (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mikepurvis/ros-install-osx/master/rosdeps.yaml)
ERROR: unable to process source [https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/rosdep/osx-homebrew.yaml]:
    <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:590)> (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/rosdep/osx-homebrew.yaml)
ERROR: unable to process source [https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/rosdep/base.yaml]:
    <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:590)> (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/rosdep/base.yaml)
ERROR: unable to process source [https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/rosdep/python.yaml]:
    <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:590)> (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/rosdep/python.yaml)
ERROR: unable to process source [https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/rosdep/ruby.yaml]:
    <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:590)> (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/rosdep/ruby.yaml)
ERROR: unable to process source [https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/releases/fuerte.yaml]:
    Failed to download target platform data for gbpdistro:
    <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:590)>
Query rosdistro index https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/index.yaml
ERROR: error loading sources list:
    <urlopen error <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:590)> (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/index.yaml)>
```

I really don't get this, because my browsers are all fine with and trust github. As they should.

I know there's already someone who asked about this error (here: http://answers.ros.org/question/47177/rosdep-update-error/ ) , but the only closure they got was to ask around where they are, so it doesn't really help me, sorry.
Important notes: I'm usually in the US but for this month I'm in Germany and I'm borrowing someone's wifi. Before you ask, I've tried using other wifi, like the one from the German university I'm at, public wifi, and I've of course tried going through my US university's vpn. I've tried adding github to my proxy-bypassing list, I've tried deleting the ssl certificate from github so it could re-download, and I've tried to follow answers from similar questions online, but they all didn't seem completely applicable to me or too hard to follow.
Can someone please help? And keep in mind that I'm not very experienced with unix commands and such, so go easy on me? ^_^;

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/241563/rosdep-update-ssl-cert-error/) by [Humoros](https://answers.ros.org/users/27735/humoros/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2016-08-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Browsers often have their top level Certificates bundled inside them so that might not be a good test.

You need to make sure that your system keychain has the ssl root certificates. From a bit of searching it looks like homebrew has provided the Mozilla ca certificates packaged as `curl-ca-bundle`

A few releated resources:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24675167/ca-certificates-mac-os-x
- https://gist.github.com/1stvamp/2158128
- http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/apple-in-the-enterprise/managing-ssl-certificate-authorities-on-os-x/ Manual approach
- http://brewformulas.org/Curl-ca-bundle

@william might have a suggestion

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2016-08-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2016-08-11**:
I don't have any suggestion beyond what you put in your answer.

**Comment by [Humoros](https://answers.ros.org/users/27735/humoros/) on 2016-08-11**:
Wow, thanks so much!! Although I had to use someone's workaround because `brew install curl-ca-bundle` didn't work directly (davestacey's answer here: https://github.com/devopsgroup-io/vagrant-digitalocean/issues/123), your thinking was spot-on and it works now! I'm so happy!

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2016-08-11**:
Glad to hear it's working. Please click the checkmark at left to indicate the question is solved for others.